# How to use public class frome .java file in other processing tabs?

Tags: java, class, processing

My problem seems to be trivial, but after 2 hours of googling I came with nothing. I have Processing sketch. The first, main tab contains:

```
Foo bar;

void setup() {
}

void draw() {
}
```

The second is Foo.java file:

```
package processing.core;
import java.io.Serializable;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Foo implements Serializable {
}
```

After I try to run this program I get at the first line of the first file:

```
Cannot find a class or type "Foo"
```

The second file is Foo.java, the first has some random name, not even simmilar, so it's not a conflict. And the file is in the same directory as the main pde file.

I work in the [Processing IDE](http://processing.org/).

What should I do to make the .java file class visible? And yes - I need .java file, since I need to use some much more complicated .java file...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you `import processing.core.Foo;`?

Comment: @Jesse Webb I upvoted too fast ;) Doesnt work, I'd update the question, but by freaky internet doesn't work correctly...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, after asking on processing.org forum one guy showed me code, which works, and after comparing them I found, that I have pointless line:

```
package processing.core;
```

Which cause problems!

So the correct code:

something.pde:

```
Foo bar;

void setup() {
}

void draw() {
}
```

Foo.java:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Foo implements Serializable {
}
```

http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/comment/12111#Comment_12111

:) However - thank you both for help!

Comment: If this solution worked, don't forget to mark the answer as "Accepted" by clicking the green check-mark beside it.

Answer (score 3):

To use class `Foo`, the class where you instantiate it must be in the same package or must be imported.

Thus, you will have to use:

```
import processing.core.Foo;
```

Comment: Ahh.. It doesn't work:

The package processing.core.Foo does not exist

Comment: So you should create appropriate folders like `processing/core`

Comment: @Jeri You mean in the sketch directory or in the libraries in the sketchbook? Does not work in either way... I tried also ./code directory. Is there any documentation for that? I spend so much time on something so trivial without success...

Answer (score 0):

This next is a working example that shows how to interact with the canvas as well:

## Sketch.pde

```
Foo bar;

void setup() {
  fill(255);
  background(0);
  textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
}

void draw() {
}

void mouseReleased(){
  bar = new Foo(this);
}
```

## Foo.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class Foo implements Serializable {

  protected final PApplet parent;
  Foo(PApplet pa) {
    parent=pa;
    pa.text("Foo created",parent.width/2,parent.height/2);
    pa.noLoop();
  }
}
```

An explanation related to this layout can be found [here](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/10342/how-can-i-build-processing-code-into-java-libraries/p1). The good bits are quoted here next as explained by GoToLoop:

> - Processing framework, in its most basic form, is the PApplet class plus a drawing canvas.
> - Functions setup(), draw(), mousePressed(), etc. are callbacks for its "Animation" Thread.
> - The "sketch" itself extends PApplet and it's a full Java class instance.
> - In order to access the canvas, we need that instance's reference/pointer.
> - Therefore, in order for a library or some other top class to be able to draw anything, it gotta request that reference.

I hope this helps,

Kf